Is there some tool so find run accessions metadata?
I have a project in which I'll use some FASTQs to feed a neural network and, as label, I'll use the estimated age range. I've got the data from AMTDB, and there they have the metadata.txt, in which we are supposed to have the metadata, including this specific data I need.
Nevertheless, most of the available FASTQs are repeated in every project id (i.e., I have project id I363 and I250 and both have the FASTQs with run access from ERR001 to ERR100).
That happens for the ~300 project ids available. That happens although the metadata of each project id indicates a different range, so I infer that the age range corresponds to a specific subset of the FASTQs.
What I'd like to know is if there's some tool available to get the metadata specific to a run access (Just like with fastq-dump it's possible to download them by RA).
Thank you in advance for any insight.

What is the AMTDB? Can you link us to it? Or at least to this metadata.txt? What age range are you referring to? Is this the age of the individual who was sequenced? The age of the file? The sequencing date? We really need to see the data to understand what you ask. Why don't you just give random names?
